# What does the following mean?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, malliavin-calculus

What does the following statement mean:

$F$ is Frechet differentiable and $\lambda^F$ denotes the signed measure associated with the Frechet derivative of $F$.

Does it mean that $\overset{.}{F}(t)=\lambda^F(t)$,i.e. $F(t)=\int_0^t \lambda^F(ds)$ or it has another meaning?

Comment: What kind of function is $F$ (domain, codomain)?

Comment: $F=f(t_1,...,t_n)$, where $f \in C_p^{\infty}(R^n)$

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for context, this is from [Nualart's book on Malliavin Calculus](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F3-540-28329-3).

[Recall that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space) $(C(\Bbb{R}))^\ast\cong \operatorname{ba}(\Bbb R)$, where $\operatorname{ba}(\Bbb R)$ is the set of regular Borel measures.

The Frechet derivative is a functional $ C(\Bbb R)\to \Bbb R$. So then it is associated with some $\mu \in \operatorname{ba}(\Bbb R)$.